# why do I get the following error: 'no such column "module"'?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Does anyone know why I get the above error?

here is the code:

This is the class that holds all of my database information:

```
package com.petroc.nationaldiploma;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TABLE_GRADES = "grades";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_GRADE = "grade";
public static final String COLUMN_MODULE = "module";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "grades.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database creation sql statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_GRADES + "(" + COLUMN_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_GRADE
        + " text not null" + COLUMN_MODULE + " text not null" + ");";

/*
 * private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " +
 * TABLE_GRADES + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
 * COLUMN_GRADE + " text not null);";
 */

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_GRADES);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

and this is the class that creates the methods used to create and manipulate the database

```
package com.petroc.nationaldiploma;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class GradesDataSource {

// Database fields
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private final MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;

  private final String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
  MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_GRADE, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MODULE };


/*private final String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
        MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_GRADE };*/

public GradesDataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}

public Grade createGrade(String grade, String module) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_GRADE, grade);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MODULE, module);
    long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_GRADES, null,
            values);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_GRADES, allColumns,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null, null,
            null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Grade newGrade = cursorToGrade(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newGrade;
}

/*
 * public Grade createGrade(String grade) { ContentValues values = new
 * ContentValues(); values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_GRADE, grade); long
 * insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_GRADES, null, values);
 * Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_GRADES, allColumns,
 * MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null, null, null);
 * cursor.moveToFirst(); Grade newGrade = cursorToGrade(cursor);
 * cursor.close(); return newGrade; }
 * 
 * public void deleteGrade(Grade grade) { long id = grade.getId();
 * System.out.println("Grade deleted with id: " + id);
 * database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_GRADES, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID +
 * " = " + id, null); }
 */

public List<Grade> getAllGrades() {
    List<Grade> grades = new ArrayList<Grade>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_GRADES, allColumns,
            null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Grade grade = cursorToGrade(cursor);
        grades.add(grade);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // Make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return grades;
}

private Grade cursorToGrade(Cursor cursor) {
    Grade grade = new Grade();
    grade.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    grade.setGrade(cursor.getString(1));
    return grade;
}
}
```

Comment: uninstall your app and run again every time you modify a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten a simple `,` after a column name in your string. That is the reason you are getting `Column Not Found`. Change

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_GRADES + "(" + COLUMN_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_GRADE
        + " text not null" + COLUMN_MODULE + " text not null" + ");";
```

to

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_GRADES + "(" + COLUMN_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_GRADE
        + " text not null, " + COLUMN_MODULE + " text not null" + ");";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I made the change but still getting the same problem :/

Comment: @ChrisBennett U checked after clearing data and reinstallation?

Comment: I got to clear data as well? I reinstalled but didn't clear the data... will try that thanks :)

Comment: It won't create database again if it already exists. So you must clear data and reinstall the application in order to force the creation of database again. @ChrisBennett

Answer (score 0):

In cursorToGrade() function, while getting values from db, you should use something like this instead of hardcoding 0 & 1.

```
grade.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID ));
grade.setGrade(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MODULE));
```

Comment: I Made the change but still getting the same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Add a space after null:

```
+ " text not null, " + COLUMN_MODULE + " text not null" + ");";
```

Comment: I made the change but still getting the same problem :/

Comment: Try adding a comma after null. The problem is in the SQl, so you can open the database on the device through dab shell, and see if the structure is correct. Make sure to recreate the table anew after any change to the create table syntax.

Answer (score 0):

see this column **COLUMN_GRADE + " text not null"**  you missing **comma(,) and space** after null.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_GRADES 
        + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
        + COLUMN_GRADE + " text not null" 
        + COLUMN_MODULE + " text not null" + ");";
```

your create table query is wrong first please correct it.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_GRADES + "(" 
        + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
        + COLUMN_GRADE + " text not null, " 
        + COLUMN_MODULE + " text not null" + ");";
```

correct this create query and delete database or uninstall your app and run again your application and check it.

I hope its Help you.

Comment: I made the change and uninstalled the app but still getting the same problem :/

Comment: did the above.

I made a table in phpmyadmin to test that it would give the same sql code to create the table and it did with a few exceptions like the + symbols which is needed by java. However I couldn't see any changes that would indicate that there was a problem with my structure

Did you mean that the query is wrong because there is no comma and space after null? If not could you please elaborate on what is wrong with it please?

Comment: Hey Chris, Are you debug your query ? if not then please print this create table variable in logcat and copy this query and run it on phpmyadmin. and then check the output.